# Oracle Data Pump Export script fails

Tags: oracle, export, datapump

I'm trying to do a data pump export for metadata on a tablespace (COURSE). Am I on the right track? My data pump directory was created as:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir AS '/mydata/data';
```

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner. This may or may not be the best way to go about this, but I'd like to try to get this working. Thanks very much.

```
declare
      dp_handle       number;
  begin
      dp_handle := dbms_datapump.open(
      operation   => 'EXPORT',
      job_mode    => 'TABLESPACE');

    dbms_datapump.add_file(
      handle    =>  dp_handle,
      filename  => 'courses.dmp',
      directory => 'dpump_dir');

    dbms_datapump.add_file(
      handle    => dp_handle,
      filename  => 'courses.log',
      directory => 'dpump_dir',
      filetype  => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);

    dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(      
      handle => dp_handle,
      name   => 'TABLESPACE_EXPR',
      value  => '''COURSE''');

    dbms_datapump.start_job(dp_handle);

    dbms_datapump.detach(dp_handle);
  end;
  /    

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 2926
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3162
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons why this could fail:

1. The file you want to write (`courses.dmp`) does *already* exist. Oracle
   won't override the file. (Yes, the error message is pretty lame)
2. The OS-directory `/mydata/data` does *not* exist.
3. `/mydata/data` *does* exist, but Oracle does not have the necessary 
   rights to access the directory
4. None of the above, but the Oracle user that runs the script was not
   granted `read, write` on `dpump_dir`

If these points don't help, you might first open (`add_file`) the *.log file, *then* the *.dmp file. Hopefully, Oracle will write something meaningful into the *.log file.

Comment: The suggestion above about adding the log file before the dmp file has been KEY to me resolving issues with the dump process.

Comment: adding the log file before the dump file has also resolved my issue when i ran into this

Answer (score 1):

It appears your error is occurring on the first ADDFILE call.

Try making your directory references upper case: directory => 'DPUMP_DIR'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(      
      handle => dp_handle,
      name   => 'TABLESPACE_EXPR',
      value  => '=''COURSE''');
```

---

> "I still get the same error messages
>   though"

Hmmm....  Remote debugging of other people's code is one of the least fun aspects of SO.  Anyway, let's give it another guess.

Do you have an OS directory called `/mydata/data` which Oracle has read and write privileges on?  The CREATE DIRECTORY statement only creates a pointer, it doesn't create the underlying OS directory.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I still get the same error messages though